# Existe alguma função no PHP que simule um LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP que precisa exibir um indicador gráfico. O problema é que os dados vem de uma API externa e dependendo do filtro aplicado, a API não me retorna pontos que preciso inserir no gráfico.

**Exemplo:**

```
// Chama a API sem filtros
$dados = $api->get()->limit(6);

var_dump($dados);
// Retorna
  'metaPontual' => 
    array (size=6)
      3 => float 178036332.62
      4 => float 176975684.39
      5 => float 173823421.06
      6 => float 170114093.13
      7 => float 168775993.4
      8 => float 167259382.68

// Aplicando um filtro
$dadosFiltrado = $api->get(['nome' => 'Lucas'])->limit(6);

var_dump($dadosFiltrado);
// O Array Não retorna todos os pontos.
  'metaPontual' => 
    array (size=6)
      1 => float 183635670.39
      4 => float 176975684.39
      5 => float 173823421.06
      6 => float 170114093.13
      8 => float 167259382.68
      9 => float 167259382.68
```

Preciso de uma rotina que atue de forma a criar um "LEFT JOIN" entre o array 1 e o array 2, lembrando que os arrays são exemplos, as chaves retornadas pelos arrays são diferentes, de modo que:

```
$arrayFinal = array_left_join(array_keys($dados), $dadosFiltrado);
var_dump($array_final)

  'metaPontual' => 
    array (size=6)
      3 => null
      4 => float 176975684.39
      5 => float 173823421.06
      6 => float 170114093.13
      7 => null
      8 => float 167259382.68
```

Comment: Seria um [`array_merge`](http://br2.php.net/array_merge) que você está buscando?

Comment: Vc quer um array novo com os valores que ambos tem em comum?

Comment: @bfavaretto não seria um array merge pois preciso somente dos valores que ambos tem em comum mais as chaves do primeiro array.

Comment: As chaves que só existem no segundo ficam de fora então?

Comment: Cara, não tem função pronta, mas brincar um pouco com uns `foreach` resolve seu problema. Eu eventualmente faço isso, mas sem tempo para dar resposta agora

Comment: @bfaretto exatamente, o que só existe no segundo array devo desconsiderar.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz pensei também em utilizar um `foreach` mas se possível gostaria de evitar seu uso por questões de desenpenho (http://www.phpbench.com/). Irei fazer alguns testes de desempenho com algumas variações do código que postei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com base nas respostas e comentários cheguei as seguintes implementações:

```
function array_left_join($arrayChaves, $arrayValores){
    $arrayIntersect = array_intersect_key($arrayValores, $arrayChaves);
    $chavesLimpas = array_fill_keys(array_keys($arrayChaves), '');

    return array_merge($chavesLimpas, $arrayIntersect);
}

function array_left_join_2($arrayChaves, $arrayValores){
    $chaves = array_keys($arrayChaves);
    $arrayFinal = array();

    foreach ($chaves as $key) {
        $arrayFinal[$key] = !isset($arrayValores[$key]) ? '' : $arrayValores[$key];
    }

    return $arrayFinal;
}
```

Aplicando essas implementações em um array bem grande cheguei aos seguintes resultados.

```
$arrayTodosOsPontos = array();
$arrayFiltrado = array();

for ($i=10; $i<100000; $i++) {
    $arrayTodosOsPontos[md5("$i")] = 1;
}

for ($i=10; $i<100000; $i++) {
    $arrayFiltrado[md5("$i")] = 4;
}

Debugbar::startMeasure('array_left_join_v1');
$arrayFinal = array_left_join($arrayTodosOsPontos, $arrayFiltrado);
Debugbar::stopMeasure('array_left_join_v1');

Debugbar::startMeasure('array_left_join_v2');
$arrayFinal2 = array_left_join_2($arrayTodosOsPontos, $arrayFiltrado);
Debugbar::stopMeasure('array_left_join_v2');
```

[image: Teste de Performance]

Como a segunda opção mostrou um desempenho melhor, acho melhor utilizar ela no projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Você disse que precisa dos valores de ambos os arrays MAIS as chaves do 1º, certo?

Tente com isso:

```
$array = array_intersect($dados, $dadosFiltrado);
$array_final = (array) ($dados + $array);

var_dump($array_final);
```

Comment: é quase isso... com array_intersect estou olhando os valores, não as chaves.

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolve seu problema

```
array_keys(array_intersect_key($arr1,$arr2));
```

Retorna um array com as chaves presentes nos dois arrays